# Regex for matching a word with multiples of each letter

Tags: regex

Sorry I have been playing around with regex for a while now and not getting anywhere.

Say my word is 'NEIGH':

```
nnnneeeiggghhhhh 
Neeeiighh
Neigh
Neeeighh
Nnnneeeigh
```

Any of the above should be able to match ^.

**My closest example:**

```
const regex = /n+e+i+g+h?(.)\1/gm;

if (regex.exec(message.content) !== null) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why not just `/n+e+i+g+h+/i` op `/\bn+e+i+g+h+\b/i`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please reply with an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/n+e+i+g+h+/i
/\bn+e+i+g+h+\b/i
```

where `+` quantifier is used after each letter, and the `i` flag enables case insensitive matching.

If the whole word must be matched, add `\b` word boundaries.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/neX6Yn/1).